# C++ templates and code generation for Variadic Sequence: How to create similar code block for each argument/type?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, code-generation, boost-preprocessor

I wonder if we could have class like this (pseudocode):

```
template <class Arg1T, ... class ArgNT>
class my_class
{
public:
    my_class(Arg1T Arg1, std::string Arg1_name  ... ArgNT  ArgN, std::string ArgN_name){}
};
```

And if we could auto generate a function for each provided argument type on compile time using defines for example to get something like (pseudocode):

```
template <class Arg1T, ... class ArgNT>
class my_class
{
public:
    my_class(Arg1T Arg1, std::string Arg1_name  ... ArgNT  ArgN, std::string ArgN_name){}
    // for each Arg we want to create a function like
    ArgMT   my_class_function(std::string name)
    {
       if(name == ArgM_name)
          return ArgM;
    }

};
```

Is such/or a bit similar thing possible in modern C++ and how to create it?

What I try to say is: I want to generate functions, for each class type provided to constructor from some function template. And wonder how to do such thing? Here is shown [how to repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291144/automatic-code-generation-in-c)  but how to repeat over provided to class arguments and thare types?

What I meant was if we'd know ammount of class templete arguments (`N`) we could create `N` variables of difrent types (one for each argument) and `N` strings  (all private) and so we could create `N` functions for setters and getters of that (strings + variables) (which we would call in constructor). Main problem here is - how to solve times when you get same types twice or more, haw to get ammount of args from boost.preprocessor, how to filter same types?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to do? What I see right now would be overloading functions based on return type.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203667/c-named-parameter-idiom-vs-boostparameter-library (and Boost Parameter library)

Comment: @sehe:  Parameter library seems quite unrelated... and does not provide any help with return types

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload functions based only on a return type, so no, it's not possible.

If you take the argument names and `my_class_function` out of the picture, you're left with `std::tuple<T0, ..., Tn>`. You can use `std::get<N>` to get N-th argument then (but it's entirely compile-time construct, N cannot be determined at runtime).

If you really need runtime handling, then mapping from `std::string` to `boost::variant` over N types might work.

Comment: @myWallJSON: `std::tuple` is compile-time. You can't use `std::string` if you want compile-time construct.

Comment: if we'd know ammount of class templete arguments (`N`)we could create `N` variables of difrent types (one for each argument) and `N` strings  (all private) and so we could create N functions for setters and getters of that string nd variables (which we would call in constructor). Main problem here is - how to solve times when you get same types twice or more.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case you could use interfaces and factory method in general.